# Can you take a log of a probability?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, modeling, model

One of the independent variable that I was going to use in my linear regression model is positively skewed. The variable is a probability and it is greater than 0.

Can you take a log of a probability?

If yes, how would you interpret it when you have the following linear regression model:

log(y) ~ log(probability_variable) + variable_2 + variable_3?

**EDIT**

Thank you for your feedback. I have included more information for context. I am trying to determine if the probability of arrest is a determinant of crime rate. Since these two variables are positively skewed and their values are greater than 0, I thought adding a log would solve its skewness and make it more normally distributed.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If your probablity include zero, what will do with log?

Comment: How you should transform it depends on your assumption of the relationship between y and probability_variable. It would be helpful if you give more details. You can check scatter plot to see if log(y)~log(p) shows linear trend. I have also seen people using log-odds: log(p/1-p)

Comment: What exactly is your data? Probability is an unobservable, abstract quantity. Interpretation would be the same as of log of anything else.

Comment: @DeepNorth Good point. It was also a concern of mine since it is a probability. I was also informed that you cannot take a log of probability which makes me prompt this question.

Comment: @Lii Great suggestion. I will read up on log-odds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show a plot of the "positive skew"? Why do you think this is something you need to be concerned about?

In linear regression what we're concerned about is that the errors are normally distributed, and we care less about the marginal distributions of the individual predictors. You may want to look at a plot of residuals vs fitted values and then determine whether or not you need to do any transformation to probability_variable. If you use R, checkout the ggfortify package.

If you do need to transform probability_var, then the interpretation is that for a unit increase in the log(probability_var) the output increases by $\beta_1$, where $\beta_1$ is the corresponding coefficient for log(probability_var)